# Updating jsonb field using concatenation operator in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update a jsonb field which has nested json objects in it using the concatenation operator in postgres  as in [dbfidde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0c7e7ba902df466a3c1657e40e5287d0)

But, it removes all other fields for example if I run the below script

```sql
UPDATE t 
SET details = details || '{"name": {"firstname": "newname"},"address":{"city":"newCity"}}'
WHERE details -> 'name' ->>'firstname'='myname'
```

It removes the `"lastname"` field from the updated field

I tried updating with `jsonb_set` too but I am not sure how I can update multiple properties using `jsonb_set`

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? As far as I understand:old JSON {"a":"b"} extend with {"a":"c"}. But than you have twice the same key...

Comment: Your dbfiddle seems to show exactly what you're asking for. Are you saying that when you do it on a real DB that the behavior is different?

Comment: @JSpratt The query in the question removes the "lastname" property as in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c13e0fe75b17567b52fe27a968a97bd7

Comment: @S-Man I am trying to update the firstname property in name object and city property in address object in the same query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` way does not work because the new name value is `{"firstname":"newname"}`. This replaces the complete old value `{"firstname": "myname","lastname":"last"}` and so removes the `lastname` attribute. This way only works if you are working on the toplevel fields. But you want to update the nested objects.

In that case I see no way around two separate calls of `jsonb_set()`. One possible way is to nest them:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6e980f37531c6b111207fa1390031a71)

```
UPDATE t
SET details = 
        jsonb_set(
            jsonb_set(details, '{name,firstname}','"newname"'), 
            '{address,city}', 
            '"newCity"'
        )
WHERE details -> 'name' ->> 'firstname' = 'myname';
```

1. Updating the original `details` field; setting the new `firstname` value through the given path `'{name,firstname}'`
2. The resulting JSON object can be used directly for a following update of the `city` value using the same way.

Comment: I am still figuring out a way,  if I have to update like 5 or even more nested objects with the above query. Do you have anything on your mind?

Comment: Maybe you can post a fiddle with your real data? I could have a look

Comment: What if I have to update `firstname, last name, homeaddress and workaddress` in a single query. Here is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=135be2934dae5c55a8f4b91346b91c00

Comment: the addresses are json objects. Would you like to replace the whole value or only replace the city element?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2585945e5a8d668e5bb87fa7b3e798f3 The name object can be aggregated in this special case because there are no further subelements. So the whole name object can be replaced in one throw. Since both cities have different paths you'll need two different calls.

Comment: I dont know, this solution works but not sure how this could handle when for different generic scenarios when I want to update few fields in one case and some other fields in another case which can act more like a function which takes some parameters

Comment: I could think about a function which takes an array of certain paths and a second one with the new values. These arrays can be looped and so for every array element can be calles: jsonb_set(myvalue, path_array[i], new_values[i]); But this is really ugly. If you really have to update the json values regularly I really recommend to store them in normalized tables instead of json objects.